# Why do I get an error in Pinescipt stating undeclared identifier?

Tags: pine-script

```
plotshape(buyCondition, title="Buy", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.label, text="BUY")
```

in the above code I get an error stating `shape` is an undeclared identifier.

How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `plotshape` that has a style of `shape.label`

If using a `plotshape` you can use any of the following styles (pic below),  otherwise you need to use the label function. You can read about labels here -[Pine Script Labels](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Text_and_shapes.html#labels)

[image: plotshape shapes]